# Ubuntu Installation of 64-bit on 32-bit OS

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have confusion of installing Ubuntu 12.04!. Actually my system is 32-bit with 4GB RAM. In the official page of Ubuntu its given as 32-bit(for machine less than than 2GB RAM). Can anyone please help me,

Thank  & Regards
Suhas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether you should run 32bit OS or 64bit OS mainly depends on your processor rather than on your RAM!

If your processor is capable of running 64bit OS (almost all latest processors are capable of running 64bit OS) Then you should install 64bit OS. If is not the case then you should install 32bit OS.

Talking about RAM:

If you install a 32bit OS then the Maximum RAM supported by your system will be 4GB.

If you install a 64bit OS then you can install more than 1TB of RAM!

have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142043/whats-the-maximum-amount-of-ram-i-can-use-on-an-specific-hardware)

Answer (score 1):

**No**. To start with, you'll lack the ability to boot or execute any of the 64-bit files. For all intents and purposes, it is essentially impossible to execute a 64-bit instruction on 32-bit hardware, and while 64-bit Ubuntu may have some 32-bit files, the main parts are 64-bit, so it won’t even boot.

Edit:
Why does Ubuntu recommend 2/4GB RAM on 32 bit machines:

`32-bit => 2^32 addressable locations = 4 GB`

`64-bit => 2^64 addressable location = 17179869184 GB`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you,then I can install 32-bit ubuntu rite ? Actually i am confused with the sentence for 32-bit ( for the machine less than 2GB RAM) because my system is 4GB RAM. Does it make any problem?