# max Memory and Storage capacity of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, lts

Does anybody know what is the maximum Memory(RAM) capacity and HDD(Storage) capacity for both 32-bit version and 64-bit version of 14.04 LTS? Same Ubuntu 13.10 32 & 64 bit versions too.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142043/whats-the-maximum-amount-of-ram-i-can-use-on-an-specific-hardware

Answer (score 2):

Linux (and therefore Ubuntu) is only limited to the physical architecture of the CPU, chipset, buses, and peripherals.

32-bit Ubuntu (which uses Physical Address Extension mode via Linux's CONFIG_X86_PAE) can use 64GB of RAM (though limited to 4GB virtual memory per process). 64-bit Ubuntu has no addressing limits, so depending on the CPU and chipset, this could be up to 256 TB (for the current generation of 48-bit physical memory CPUs). Most systems will be limited by their chipset and RAM sockets.

For more details, see [Larger physical address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

Hard drive size again depends on the hardware, not Ubuntu. The standard filesystem, [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), can address up to 1 [exbibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exbibyte).

Answer (score 0):

32bit RAM is 4G addressable
64bit RAM is  16.8 million terabytes

Hard drive space is harder as it depends on file system, hardware and the like. Last time I checked max file size on ext2/3/4 was 8 Petabytes. You can probably say that hardware will limit file system or file size before Ubuntu or Linux would.